# Excel Pivot Table with dates not grouping by years

Tags: excel, pivot-table

My column data has dates and blanks, and I would like to get rid of the blanks so my pivot table will group by years (that's my though I don't know if that's what happen).

[image]

Hiding the blanks at the pivot table is not working either.

Comment: I suspect there is a space, or non-printing character, (or formula) in that cell.  You probably need to make it really blank before you create the pivot table.

Comment: BTW, if, for some reason, you cannot "blank" that cell, you could process your data using Power Query (available in Excel 2010+) and accomplish your goal that way.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld this is the query which I get the data from ````if (dateMeeting is null, "", dateMeeting) as "Date Meeting",```` as you can see, date or nohing "".

Comment: Is that a formula in the cell?  If so, then it is not "blank".  And if it is part of a query, then try changing it to place a `null` in the cell.  The Pivot Table does not see `""` and `null` as the same.

Comment: Ok I'll try setting blanks to null, thanks mate.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld well now when I create the pivot table one row is "(blank)", instead of "", but it's still appearing...